# Summation formula for twisted L-function

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, modular-forms, l-functions

Does any expert here know something about the summation formula of the Voronoi type for the sum $$\sum_{n\le X} a_{f}(n)\chi(n) e\left(\frac{an}{c}\right)?$$

Here $f$ is a newform of level $N$, $\chi$ is a 
primitive Dirichlet character modulo $N$, and $a,c$ are co-prime integers satisfying $(c,N)=1$.

Much obliged if anyone  could give some comments or guide the references. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try Appendix A of "Rankin-Selberg $L$-functions in the level aspect" by Kowalski, Michel, and Vanderkam. (Note that $a_f(n) \chi(n)$ is basically equal to $a_{f \otimes \chi}(n)$.)

Comment: @ Peter Humphries Thanks for comments.